# how to give curlup effect on splitview application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

in my mac i have ver 3.2.5 xcode
  i create spliteview application i have problem with curl effect 
  when i click on left side view on cell then right side detailview must be open with curl up
i want to give curlup only detailview not on all splitiew i want just like culture code application name is think

this is code i try but it working on whole splitview i want to run curlup only detailview when i select cell from left side view

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
   // NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;

    UIViewController <SubstitutableDetailViewController> *detailViewController = nil;

    if ([indexPath row] == 0 && [indexPath section] == 0) {
        TodoDetailViewController *newDetailViewController = [[TodoDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TodoDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
        detailViewController = newDetailViewController;
    }

    if ([indexPath row] == 0 && [indexPath section] == 1){
        PeopleViewController *newDetailViewController = [[PeopleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PeopleViewController" bundle:nil];
        detailViewController = newDetailViewController;
    }

    if ([indexPath row] == 1 && [indexPath section] == 1){
        DocumentsViewController *newDetailViewController = [[DocumentsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DocumentsViewController" bundle:nil];
        detailViewController = newDetailViewController;
    }

    if ([indexPath row] == 2 && [indexPath section] == 1){
        PlannerViewController *newDetailViewController = [[PlannerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlannerViewController" bundle:nil];
        detailViewController = newDetailViewController;
    }

    //if ([indexPath row] == 0 && [indexPath section] == 2){
//        PlannerRequestsViewController *newDetailViewController = [[PlannerRequestsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlannerRequestsViewController" bundle:nil];
//        detailViewController = newDetailViewController;
//    }

    if ([indexPath row] == 0 && [indexPath section] == 2){
        ArchivedPeopleViewController *newDetailViewController = [[ArchivedPeopleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ArchivedPeopleViewController" bundle:nil];
        detailViewController = newDetailViewController;
    }


    // Update the split view controller's view controllers array.
   //NSArray *viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.navigationController, detailViewController, nil];
   // splitViewController.viewControllers = viewControllers;

    //new try-----today
    //splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray
                                     //  arrayWithObjects:masterView, detailsView, nil];
    splitViewController.viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.navigationController, detailViewController, nil];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:splitViewController.view cache:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:splitViewController.view cache:YES];
```

by

```
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:detailViewController.view cache:YES];
```

*UPDATE ***

In TodoDetailsViewContrroller.h

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: niko i try ur ans but when i click on left side cell it open simple way it’s not open with curl effect how to give curl up animation help me this is importance for me

Comment: Maybe you can try to move your view animation inside the viewWillAppear function of each of your UIViewController. In the meantime, I'll think of a better solution

Comment: like this i already try nothing to happen friend we have to do some diffrent i search lot of but not found any think yet

Comment: ok, I'll do some tests when i'll be at work :). Keep you updated.